# Openlayers3 how to get the max feature id in postgis through geroserver

Tags: openlayers-3

I want to use the openlayers 3 to get the maximum feature id stroted in postgis through the geoserver, does someone have ideas. I have tried with CQL in openlayers3, but the sytax is not right, i cannot find the good example from internet to show how the openlayers3 use the cql to query sth from geoserver.
Does someone have some examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont need openlayers or even CQL to do that. 
Just execute a get request to your geoserver as follows:

`http://yourhost:port/geoserver/wfs?request=GetFeature&typeName=namespace:featuretype&propertyName=ID&version=1.0.0&sortBy=ID+D&maxFeatures=1`

So lets see our parametes

`&typeName=namespace:featuretype` -->this is your layer name

`&propertyName=ID` --> these are the attributes should get back on response.Add more attributes using comma

`&sortBy=ID+D` --> this means to sort the results using ID field and `+D` means in descending order

`&maxFeatures=1` -->return only one fetaure.

So to summarise. Mr Geoserver give me back only one feature, from layer "namespace:featuretype" ordered by id, in a descending order.
More info [here](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/services/wfs/reference.html)

Comment: thanks  it is nice, for further question based on it, I want to get the number of total feature in the database, is there some simple ways to do

Comment: for propertyName=ID, could you give a example

Comment: `localhost:8080/mapassist_geoserver281/mapassist/wfs?request=GetFeature&typeName=mapassist:pand_denbosch&version=1.1.0&sortBy=gid+D&maxFeatures=1`    the propertyname=gid   doesnt work, and make unexception error

Comment: What error???? Is the `gid` a proper field within the database table???? For the total features add `&resultType=hits` to your url and remove the `&maxFeatures=1`

Comment: // $http.get('http://dbgeo01.csampubdemo.net.crotecvps.nl:8080/mapassist_geoserver281/mapassist/wfs?request=GetFeature&typeName=mapassist:pand_denbosch&version=1.0.0&sortBy=gid+D&maxFeatures=1')
  // .success(function(data) {
  // console.log(data);
  // });
PLEASE CHECK IT, IT IS PUBLIC SERVER, U CAN TEST IT

Comment: `http://dbgeo01.csampubdemo.net.crotecvps.nl:8080/mapassist_geoserver281/mapassist/wfs?request=GetFeature&typeName=mapassist:pand_denbosch&version=1.0.0&sortBy=gid+D&maxFeatures=1`

Comment: PLEASE TRY ADD propertyName=gid

Comment: gid is primary key in database

Comment: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.util.Collection java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.util.Collection

Comment: correct I was missing this. try it now `http://dbgeo01.csampubdemo.net.crotecvps.nl:8080/mapassist_geoserver281/mapassist/wfs?request=GetFeature&service=WFS&propertyName=gid&typeName=mapassist:pand_denbosch&version=1.0.0&sortBy=gid+D&maxFeatures=1`

Comment: also for the total features use this-->`http://dbgeo01.csampubdemo.net.crotecvps.nl:8080/mapassist_geoserver281/mapassist/wfs?request=GetFeature&typeName=mapassist:pand_denbosch&version=1.1.0&resultType=hits`

Comment: since it return the a json string.  i only need the largest id value, do u have some ways parse it to get from the the responded data

Comment: well by deafult returns gml. unless you ask for json as output format. like so `http://dbgeo01.csampubdemo.net.crotecvps.nl:8080/mapassist_geoserver281/mapassist/wfs?request=GetFeature&service=WFS&propertyName=gid&typeName=mapassist:pand_denbosch&version=1.1.0&sortBy=gid+D&maxFeatures=1&outputFormat=application/json` then you can get the max gid like so `json.features[0].properties.gid` where json is you json response

Comment: From your idea, that means there is no way to parse value from gml string for a specific value directlt, right?    and the url link for the number of feature `http://dbgeo01.csampubdemo.net.crotecvps.nl:8080/mapassist_geoserver281/‌​mapassist/wfs?request=GetFeature&typeName=mapassist:pand_denbosch&version=1.1.0&r‌​esultType=hits`  I got many mumbers, it is not a gml string

Comment: numberOfFeatures="1000000"   I got this,  but it is wrong, the database should't be this value, should have more

Comment: 10000 is the limit you use within your geoserver configuration. You need to check `Ignore maximum number of features when calculating hits`.check it the docs here-->http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/webadmin/services/WFS.html. Dont forget to reload your geoserver afterwards

Comment: also, there are many different ways to parse the gml. One is using the `ol.format.GML` but I am not familiar with it, as using json is much faster.

Comment: I found you posted url link   and another link created by me, gave different data, yours is all  numbers looks like all data from database, but mine is a gml string just show numver of feature, i compared it t url strings are same, too werid. `http://dbgeo01.csampubdemo.net.crotecvps.nl:8080/mapassist_geoserver281/mapassist/wfs?request=GetFeature&typeName=mapassist:pand_denbosch&version=1.1.0&r‌​esultType=hits`  `http://dbgeo01.csampubdemo.net.crotecvps.nl:8080/mapassist_geoserver281/mapassist/wfs?request=GetFeature&typeName=mapassist:pand_denbosch&version=1.1.0&resultType=hits`

Comment: the problem looks like from resultType=hits, but they are same actually

Comment: hmm, i found that if i copy from this web,    or type in url by myself,  they have different result.  Wierd.